# sphinx customization of latexpdf output?

Tags: latex, pdflatex, python-sphinx

Just curious if anyone knows how to customize the sphinx output when using the latexpdf target? I've seen lots of custom stuff for html output, but cant seem to find any example of custom pdf output.

Specifically, I'd be interested in customizing the title page, headers, footers, and possibly adding a few pages of front matter before the contents.

Has anyone seen any examples of this kind of customization, or do people pretty much just use the "stock" sphinx output when generating pdfs? Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

Yes i think better or clearer documentation for latex styling would be nice and 
some examples.

Here is a question on the sphinx mailing list, which is about about using packages.

sphinx has its own latex documentclass in a file called sphinxmanual.cls or 
sphinxhowto.cls, if i remember correctly its a report documentclass that is used as base.
then there is 2 style files, which are the packages, it is those files contents
that are called on when you write \usepackage{mylatexstilefile}

Question about using latex packages 
http://groups.google.com/group/sphinx-dev/browse_thread/thread/890dab5e53fff004

Here is my conf.py.

```
preamb_old = ur'''
  %\documentclass{memoir}
  \makeatletter
  \fancypagestyle{normal}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{{\py@HeaderFamily\thepage}}
    \fancyfoot[LO]{{\py@HeaderFamily\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}
    \fancyfoot[RE]{{\py@HeaderFamily\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{{\py@HeaderFamily \@title}} % here's the change
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
  }
  \makeatother
  %\color {blue}
  %\normalcolor {dark blue}
  \pagecolor [RGB]{255, 247, 226}
  \definecolor{VerbatimColor}{rgb}{0.95,0.85,0.65}
  \definecolor{VerbatimBorderColor}{rgb}{0.5,0.95,0.1}
'''

f = open('graph/static/latexstyling.tex', 'r+')
PREAMBLE = f.read();


latex_elements = {
   'papersize':'a4paper',
   'pointsize':'11pt',
   'classoptions': ',openany',
   'babel': '\\usepackage[english]{babel}',
   'preamble': PREAMBLE

}
```

i don't use preamble_old anymore, but it is an example of changes directly in
conf.py, to your latex preamble.

Check out latex_elements and latex_additional_files in the sphinx docs as
a starting point.

Comment: sorry the formatting crapped out, it looked ok in the preview!

Comment: @pyfunc: I am getting `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.` for this idea. Do you know why?

Comment: The Google groups link does not work. But this one does: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sphinx-users/iQ2rXlP_8AQ